# bxSlider: add a css class only on last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

Is it possible to add a class **only** on last slide and remove the class again when the slider start to loop with first slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bxslider.com/options look Callbacks section in there and use it. The answer is yes you able to add or remove class to current.